# Spring Data Neo4j and entity being @RelatedTo in collection and in other entity - relationship not created

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Today I was struggling with `SDN` and my model.

Basically what I want to achieve is to have `Foo` entity relation to `Bar` entites but also I need to keep `nextBar` relation in each `Bar` entity to easily check some properties of `nextBar` (`Bar`s are ordered).

I wanted to achieve this by using :

```
package neo4j.example.domain;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedTo;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@NodeEntity
public class Foo {

    @GraphId
    public Long id;

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo
    public Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", bars=" + bars +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and

```
package neo4j.example.domain;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedTo;

@NodeEntity
public class Bar {

    @GraphId
    public Long id;

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo
    public Bar nextBar;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bar{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", nextBar=" + nextBar +
                '}';
    }
}
```

but I encountered problem in my project unit tests (some of them didn't pass). After some investigation I discovered that if I persist the data in one go:

```
public class AllInOneTest {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ExampleNeo4jConfiguration.class);
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = context.getBean(GraphDatabaseService.class);
    Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations = context.getBean(Neo4jOperations.class);
    FooRepository fooRepository = context.getBean(FooRepository.class);
    ExecutionEngine executionEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService);

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        executionEngine.execute(CLEAN_DATABASE_QUERY);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldProperlyCreateRelationships(){
        // given
        Bar firstBar = new Bar();
        Bar secondBar = new Bar();
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        firstBar.nextBar = secondBar;
        foo.bars.addAll(Arrays.asList(firstBar, secondBar));

        // when
        fooRepository.save(foo);

        // then
        Foo retrievedFoo = fooRepository.findOne(foo.id);
        System.out.println(retrievedFoo);
        for(Bar bar: retrievedFoo.bars) {
            if(firstBar.id.equals(bar.id)){
                Assert.assertNotNull(bar.nextBar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
Foo{id=0, bars=[Bar{id=2, nextBar=Bar{id=1, nextBar=null}}, Bar{id=1, nextBar=null}]}
```

from my `System.out.println` so everything persisted the way I wanted.

But usually I am not getting all `Bar`s in one go (user adds one `Bar` and after 5 minutes user adds second `Bar`) - and here is the problem.

```
package neo4j.example;

import neo4j.example.configuration.ExampleNeo4jConfiguration;
import neo4j.example.domain.Bar;
import neo4j.example.domain.Foo;
import neo4j.example.repository.FooRepository;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static neo4j.example.repository.Query.CLEAN_DATABASE_QUERY;

public class OneByOneTest {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ExampleNeo4jConfiguration.class);
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = context.getBean(GraphDatabaseService.class);
    FooRepository fooRepository = context.getBean(FooRepository.class);
    ExecutionEngine executionEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService);

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        executionEngine.execute(CLEAN_DATABASE_QUERY);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldProperlyCreateRelationships(){
        // given
        Bar firstBar = new Bar();
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        foo.bars.add(firstBar);
        fooRepository.save(foo);

        // when
        Bar secondBar = new Bar();
        Foo firstRetrievedFoo = fooRepository.findOne(foo.id);
        Bar[] bars = firstRetrievedFoo.bars.toArray(new Bar[0]);
        bars[0].nextBar = secondBar;
        firstRetrievedFoo.bars.add(secondBar);

        System.out.println(firstRetrievedFoo);
        fooRepository.save(firstRetrievedFoo);
        System.out.println(firstRetrievedFoo);

        // then
        // then
        Foo retrievedFoo = fooRepository.findOne(foo.id);
        System.out.println(retrievedFoo);
        for(Bar bar: retrievedFoo.bars) {
            if(firstBar.id.equals(bar.id)){
                Assert.assertNotNull(bar.nextBar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code on empty database prints:

```
Foo{id=125130, bars=[Bar{id=125131, nextBar=Bar{id=null, nextBar=null}}, Bar{id=null, nextBar=null}]}
Foo{id=125130, bars=[Bar{id=125131, nextBar=Bar{id=125132, nextBar=null}}, Bar{id=125132, nextBar=null}]}
Foo{id=125130, bars=[Bar{id=125132, nextBar=null}, Bar{id=125131, nextBar=null}]}
```

And the test fails. I can see that before and after persisting the relationship to new `nextBar` is pointing where I want it to. After retrieving `Foo` from the repository it is set to null.

Here is the example project: https://github.com/Adebski/neo4j-relatedto-problem/

I am using simple mapping and embedded version of `Neo4j`. Advanced mapping is currently not an option for me because my normal project is in `Scala` with `SBT` and AFAIK this combination with `SDN` advanced mapping does not work.

Comment: Same issue but it occurs randomly ... what solution do you end up with?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is the small function I written to go around this problem. Basically I am manually creating missing relationships. https://gist.github.com/Adebski/16867f4c464132f61317

But also I was thinking on migrating the addition operation to queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried issuing save(firstBar) separately (after setting nextBar on it) to see if that helps? It might be that the cascading save doesn't work the way you think - i.e. I know it will persist any detached entities but I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't updating all the properties/relationship of already existing nodes. Generally speaking if I remember correctly by default the @RelatedTo only retrieves the id of the connected nodes, unless it's annotated with @Fetch. Therefore, I don't think it would have an easy way of determining that you added a relationship to it, or changed a property.